# How to convert a Java object to a SQL Server table valued parameter from java code

Tags: java, sql-server

How to convert a Java object to a SQL Server table-valued-parameter?

```java
public class User {
    private int userId; 
    private String firstName; 
    private String lastName; 
    private String gender; 
    private String city;
}
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEST_USER]( 
    [USER_ID] [int] NOT NULL, 
    [FIRST_NAME] [varchar](100) NULL, 
    [LAST_NAME] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [GENDER] [varchar](10) NULL, 
    [CITY] [varchar](30) NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY ( [USER_ID] )
); 

CREATE TYPE USERTYPE AS TABLE ( 
    USER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL , 
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(100), 
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(100), 
    GENDER VARCHAR(10), 
    CITY VARCHAR(30) 
); 

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_InsertUser @UserDetail USERTYPE READONLY  
AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON
  INSERT INTO TEST_USER (USER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, GENDER,CITY) 
   SELECT [USER_ID], [FIRST_NAME], [LAST_NAME],[GENDER],[CITY] FROM @UserDetail 
END
```

I want to convert an object of User class to a (SQL Server)USERTYPE  Table Type

Comment: Are you looking for Hibernate (http://hibernate.org/) ?

Comment: I want to pass a java object as a SQL Server table valued parameter to a sql server stored procedure from java code

Comment: You need to write a util method to do so. No inbuilt methods.

Comment: can you tell logic/code snippet required to do that ?

Comment: Show **your** code first - i.e. your Java class and the table structure (ideally the CREATE TABLE statement). We need to know what are your trying to convert into what to give you a relewant advice.

Comment: Use the edit link in the question to add the code there (and delete the comments)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following logic in JDBC:

```
SQLServerDataTable table = new SQLServerDataTable();
table.addColumnMetadata("USER_ID", Types.INTEGER);
table.addColumnMetadata("FIRST_NAME", Types.VARCHAR);
table.addColumnMetadata("LAST_NAME", Types.VARCHAR);
table.addColumnMetadata("GENDER", Types.VARCHAR);
table.addColumnMetadata("CITY", Types.VARCHAR);
table.addRow(
    user.getUserId(),
    user.getFirstName(),
    user.getLastName(),
    user.getGender(),
    user.getCity()
);

try (SQLServerPreparedStatement stmt=
    (SQLServerPreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(
       "{ call SP_InsertUser (?) }")) {

    stmt.setStructured(1, "dbo.usertype", table);  
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

[I have described this also in this blog post here](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/01/10/jooq-3-10-will-support-sql-servers-table-valued-parameters/).